# Regex for all characters and interpunction

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, forum

I'm scraping forum pages with python.

I need to get all the messages and messages need to have all the punctuation characters. But I need to remove all the spaces.

I tried to do that with this code: But I don't have . * and other in my output.

```
    found = [re.sub("[.*]+", " ", d.text.encode("utf-8").decode("utf-8"))]
    rez.extend(found)

for line in rez:
    line = re.sub(r'^\s+$|\n', '', line)
    text_file.write(line + "\n\n")
    print(line)
```

Comment: If you want to remove all the spaces, what's wrong with `found = ''.join(text.split())`?

Comment: Or simply [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)?

Comment: @MichaelFranzen - Because `str.replace` operates with specific strings, not sequences of any whitespace. You'd have to do a `replace` for each possible whitespace character.

Comment: `re.sub("[.*]+", " ", s)` replaces all runs consisting of `.` and `*` into a single space; effectively, it removes all periods and stars. You say that you didn't want that; if so, why did you do it?

Answer (score -1):

To remove all spaces from a string `line` you can simply do:

```
re.sub("\s", "",line)
```

This will keep all other punctuation and only remove spaces.